# facebook API login and data management

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was looking at the facebook [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/getting-started-web/) here

I am having some generic questions about integration and data management of user profiles (slightly confused).

So let's forget the facebook API for a minute, upon normal sign up I use a database that I capture the user details like desired user name , password and email ,dob .

If I use the facebook api shall I write tjose details anyway on my db and create a random username / password  for the user and associate it with the facebook name (create a new field) or it's best not to write any information on my db at all? And then they can just use fb every time that they need to login .
I guess fb login takes away the username and password completely and still provides me with some information e.g email , date of birth etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you will need some way to differentiate between Facebook users and users that have logged in manually. They will pretty much share the same fields (you can even request the users DOB from Facebook).

In both scenarios, you'll want to have a record in your DB for the user. With regard to a unique identifier, you could easily use the user's Facebook ID. After the user has logged in, you should not differentiate between login methods.

Comment: Thanks, I am using the users email as a unique identifier and I have another field authtype in the DB if the user has logged in with facebook.